# proving condition for a non constant function $f(x)$

Tags: functions

> For all $x\in [1,2]$, Let $f''(x)$ of a non constant function $f(x)$ exists and satisfy $|f''(x)|\leq 2$
>
> If $f(1) = f(2)\;,$ Then Prove that there exists some $c\in (1,2)$ such that $f'(c)=0$
>
> Also prove that at least one $d\in (1,2)$ such that $f'(d)>0$ and $|f'(x)|<2\forall x \in [1,2]$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $|f''(x)|\leq 2\Rightarrow -2 \leq f''(x)\leq 2$

So $$-2\int dx \leq \int f''(x)dx \leq 2\int dx$$

$$-2x\leq f'(x)\leq 2\Rightarrow |f'(x)|\leq 2x$$
Now how can i solve it , Help required, Thanks

Comment: The first part is the Rolle's theorem. You need to ensure that $f$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ and differentiable on $(1,2)$. Also, don't you think we should integrate in the proper interval?$-2\int_1^2\,dx\leq \int_1^2f''(x)\,dx\leq 2\int_1^2\,dx$

$\Rightarrow -2\le f'(2)-f'(1)\le2$

Answer (score 2):

Using Rolle's Theorem on $f$ you can prove the existence of the point $c\in (1,2)$ such that $f^\prime (c)=0$. ( $f$ is differentiable since if has a second derivative on $[1,2]$).

Assume to the contrary that at no point is the first derivative positive. That would mean that the function $f$ is non-increasing on the whole interval $[1,2]$, and since $f(1)=f(2)$, we have that $f$ must be a constant function which is contrary to the starting assumption.

Using Lagrange's theorem on $f^\prime$ we have that for each $x\in [1,2]$ there exists a point $e\in (1,2)$ such that $ | f^\prime (x)-f^\prime(c) | = |f^{\prime \prime} (e) (x-c) |$. We have that $| f^\prime (x) | = | f^{\prime \prime} (e) | | x-c | \leq 2 $